# Using SELECT to select 10 rows with distinction on one column

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, distinct

Here is sales table.Here there 7 records.

```
+--------------+-------+------+-------+------------+---------+
| customername | price | vat  | total | billnumber | salesid |
+--------------+-------+------+-------+------------+---------+
| Raju         |  1300 |  165 |  1300 |         41 |      61 |
| Raju         |  1300 |  165 |  1300 |         42 |      62 |
| tubemania    |   670 | 2266 | 17890 |         45 |      67 |
| tubemania    |   220 | 2266 | 17890 |         45 |      68 |
| tubemania    | 17000 | 2266 | 17890 |         45 |      69 |
| tubemania    |   670 | 2266 | 17890 |         46 |      70 |
| tubemania    |   220 | 2266 | 17890 |         46 |      71 |
+--------------+-------+------+-------+------------+---------+
```

**What i want to do?**

**1. I want to select 3 records with different billnumber order by salesid.(records should be with all the columns)**

**Note :** i mean the result should be like the one below.**

```
+--------------+-------+------+-------+------------+---------+
| customername | price | vat  | total | billnumber | salesid |
+--------------+-------+------+-------+------------+---------+
| Raju         |  1300 |  165 |  1300 |         41 |      61 |
| Raju         |  1300 |  165 |  1300 |         42 |      62 |
| tubemania    |   670 | 2266 | 17890 |         45 |      67 |
| tubemania    |   220 | 2266 | 17890 |         45 |      68 |
| tubemania    | 17000 | 2266 | 17890 |         45 |      69 |
+--------------+-------+------+-------+------------+---------+
```

**What i meant?**

Here you can see there are 5 records **(but i said three)** but these records contains only three different bill number.

**Please suggest me a MYSQL query** for this problem. If I am not clear enough, please comment.

Comment: what have you tried? it looks like homework... you can read here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/select.html

Comment: @jcho360 http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html for English documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You should select the unique values of the distinct column first. In another query you can fetch all rows, using the values from the first query to filter in your `where` clause. Merry coding.

Comment: yeah you are right but i hope there we would be a way to perform this thing in a single query.

Comment: I think you could, if you do an inner join. On one side you have the whole set with all columns, on the other side you have a search on the same table but fetching only that column with distinct values. I don't know if that would work and I can't test right now. But it would still be a couple queries, even if you can execute them both at once with a single command.

Comment: hmm.yeah it still would be having two or more queries.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for your requirement.

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER
WHERE BILLNUMBER IN(
    SELECT DISTINCT BILLNUMBER
    FROM CUSTOMER LIMIT 0,3);
```

Comment: change limit 0,3 to limit 3

Comment: Will it make any difference?

Comment: I am getting this error.What should i do?
ERROR 1235 (42000): This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/AN
Y/SOME subquery'